# Autoregression for 20 numbers

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

If I had 20 numbers over a certain time period say 20 days and would like to figure out the next 5 numbers in the series, I am assuming I use an AR(20) Autoregression. However, I don't know how to do this type of calculation. Can someone please help me figure this out? T o give an idea of what I mean here, I would like to take a Bollinger band calculation and turn it into an autoregressive model. The Middle band is calculated as the mean of the last twenty closing prices. The top and bottom bands are calculated as 2 standard deviations above and below the mean. I am trying to figure out how put this information into a autoregression model and run it for 5 periods. So if it were 20 days worth of data which is the amount required to calculate Bollinger bands, I would like to know what the closing prices should be for days 21-25 are and then compare to actual observed data. I have read about ARMA and I found that it must be stationary. Obviously this can't be stationary as a stock price wouldn't automatically bring itself back to mean 0 frequently. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty broad request, clint, and so it might be considered too much to handle in one go. Have you searched our site for threads about AR (or ARIMA) models, [tag:time-series], forecasting, and related terms? Reading a few of them might give you some ideas about how to focus your question.  Additional pointers can be found in our [help].

Comment: I have but i found that the ARIMA Models must be stationary and i need this to be non-stationary. I will keep searching. thanks.

Comment: There are already several more questions implied in that comment! I suspect that if you backed off a little from your immediate technical concern and considered providing some context for your situation, along with an explanation of your goals, then you might be able to direct and refocus this thread into a line of inquiry that is more fruitful for you and inspires your readers to give appropriate, useful answers.

Comment: I understand. I am new to this and trying to learn. Its been many years since i have done math and i remember nothing from Differential equations and very little calculus. I am not sure how to phrase the question differently. The way I am looking at this question is the way a Bollinger band is set up. It uses the last twenty closing prices with a mean of those prices being the middle band and the top and bottom bands are 2 std dev. above and below the middle band. I would like to look at that in terms at looking at what an autoregression would look like for future prices and then compare.

Comment: That is important contextual information, clint.  Please don't bury it in a comment: feel free to keep editing your post until it conveys your situation clearly and accurately to your readers (without relying on information in the comments, which often gets overlooked or deleted eventually).